# Accessing one model from another

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, model

I have a model method that performs an algorithm, and there is another model that, after saving, in some cases, needs to refresh the algorithm result.

So, I would like to be able to do something like this:

```
class Model1 < ActiveRecord::Base
  after_save :update_score

  def update_score
    if ...
      ...
    else
      # run_alg from class Model2
    end
  end
end

class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def run_alg
    ...
  end
end
```

Is this possible or do I have to move/copy `run_alg` into application.rb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If it is a class method, you can just call `Model2.run_alg`, otherwise if it's an instance method you need to have an instance of Model2, which can be called like `@model2_instance.run_alg` (where @model2_instance is an instance variable of Model2).

Class Method:

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.run_alg
    ...
  end

  # or

  class << self
     def run_alg
     ...
     end
  end
end
```

Instance method:

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def run_alg
    ...
  end
end
```

To read more on class methods and instance methods, [check this out](http://railstips.org/blog/archives/2009/05/11/class-and-instance-methods-in-ruby/).

Answer (score 2):

Change method in your `Model2` to `instance_method` by adding `self.`

```
class Model2 < ActiveRecord::Base
  def self.run_alg
    ...
  end
end
```

And call it from `Model1` as `Model2.run_alg`

Comment: doesn't adding self turn it into a `class_method`?