# How to reference one model from inside another model?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm trying to send an event invitation to a user if they already exist in my system and a website invitation if the user (email address) isn't already in my system. Here's how I'm trying to do it:

```
  def self.lookup_and_send_emails(emails, msg)
    addresses = split_addresses(emails)
    addresses.each do |email|
      if Users.where(email: :email)
         SwapMailer.babysitter_request.deliver
      else
        #send the devise/website invitation
      end
    end
  end
```

but what this gives me is:

```
 uninitialized constant Event::Users
```

How can I reach my Users model from my Events model. I could move this to the controller but I'm trying to keep my controller "skinny".

Comment: this may help http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5385051/accessing-one-model-from-another

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you are utilising the model Class it is singular. The correct syntax is:

```
if User.where(email: :email)
  SwapMailer.babysitter_request.deliver
else
  #send the devise/website invitation
end
```

Comment: probably check the length or the count, it won't be nil - i.e. `if User.where(email: :email).count == 0` or `if User.where(email: :email).any?`